# Bootstrap modal dialog is disabled in a project where Material modules are added

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material, modal-dialog, disable

I am transferring my Bootstrap based Angular 11 project to Material based.
Menu, Sidenav and new Material based components are working well.
However my old Bootstrap based components having Modal dialogs started from a button press are shown as disabled and not reacting to anything. The exactly same code works well without Material modules included.

Immediately when I a add the Material components `MatButtonModule,MatExpansionModule,MatIconModule, MatListModule,MatMenuModule, MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule` to my `app.module.ts`, which are needed for the menu system the Bootstrap based Modal dialog in another component stops working (stays disabled).

There seems to be a problem with the concurrent use of Material and Bootstrap in this case. Is it possible to avoid it or is the only way to move all current bootstrap based modal dialogs to Material.

**Dialog using Material modules in project**
[image: Dialog using Material modules in project]

**Same dialog using only Bootstrap**
[image: Same dialog using only Bootstrap]

Comment: Do you want to open material dialog or bootstrap dialog?

Comment: From a bootstrap based component I want to open a bootstrap modal dialog.  My previous "only bootstrap"-based version with exactly the same code works fine. Now when I have added Material modules to app.module the same component stops working. This concerns only the part where I try to open a modal dialog. The dialog is then disabled. This has to do with adding of Material modules. As soon as I remove them the modal dialog works fine again. BengtBr

Comment: Most of the discussions related to this same problem are about background overlay that has a larger z-index or changing modal-background style. I have tried changing these but with no success. I don't know if using Material modules somehow change styling, but using Material causes this problem.

Comment: @BengtBr did you already find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue when upgrading to Angular 14.2 and ng-bootstrap 13.0 (angular/material integrated). It's also mentioned on their [GitHub](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/4406).

Currently, we solved it by overriding the modal class in our style with a higher z-index then 1050.